# Counter-intuitive results when mixing dataclass and enum

Tags: python, enums, python-dataclasses

A colleague of mine just tried mixing dataclass and enum, and got some weird result:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass 
from enum import Enum

@dataclass
class MyClass(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

```py
>>> MyClass.A == MyClass.B
True
```

While we quickly realized that the `@dataclass` was irrelevant here (a simple enum is fine), we are still wondering why `MyClass` is behaving this way.

---

Additional info/things we tried below:

```py
>>> MyClass.A
MyClass()
>>> type(MyClass.A)
<enum 'MyClass'>
>>> type(MyClass)
<class 'enum.EnumMeta'>
>>> @dataclass
... class MyClass2(int):
...     A = 1
...     B = 2
... 
>>> 
>>> print(MyClass2.A == MyClass2.B)  # Works fine with 'int'
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observation: `dataclass` and `Enum` were not designed to work together.

The specific issue you are experiencing:

- `dataclass` replaces the `__eq__` method
- the dataclass `__eq__` method is comparing the values of the dataclass fields
- there are no dataclass fields
- so they compare equal

`Enum`'s `__eq__`, on the other hand, knows to compare the `.value` of each member.

Comment: untrue, because `A` and `B` are not dataclass fields to begin with. you can confirm this is the case, with `assert dataclasses.fields(MyClass) == ()`

Comment: @rv.kvetch: Thanks, that makes sense.  I tried reading the `dataclass` code but couldn't figure it out.  Answer updated.

Comment: Yep, this seems to check out. Worth noting that `MyClass2.A is MyClass2.B` is false, so they aren't actually the same object, just comparing equal. Lesson of the day: Don't combine these two features.

Comment: and just adding for clarification, but the reason they're not fields is because they currently don't have type annotations. so for example `A: int = 1` would be a field, no problem. once turned into dataclass fields, I believe you would actually encounter the `__eq__` issue, as mentioned in the answer as well.

Comment: @rv.kvetch: fyi I tried it and did encounter the `__eq__` as you said.

Thanks a lot to everyone for the insights and explanations!